# CDX File not update after add a new recoed into DBF File

Tags: visual-foxpro, dbf

I would like to add a new record into dbf File(file name is STCRD.dbf). I added a new record by using visual studio 2017 > data connectionse as below picture.

[image]

After a new record is added, the cdx file, which is name STCRD.cdx, is not updated. I'm a newbie in visual foxpro. I still did not know after cdx file is changed, the dbf file should be changed as well or not. Can anyone point me to the correct way to add a new record into this kind of database?

I found some [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=433308) that contain some information, but I cannot understand the answer about issueing the pack command.

Comment: You would only use the path in your connection string. Other than that, your commands are missing. How are you doing your insert/update/delete? If you let VS generate commands, then beware VS does that wrong for VFP.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check other posts about working with VFP and OleDb connections.  The connection should point to the PATH that the files are located, not the individual file names / dbf / cdx / fpt.

So your connection string should point to just the

D:\Work\Sirichai\TNPSE

Then your select, insert, update, delete can just refer to the table and SHOULD work without issue...

select * from STCRD where ....

insert into STCRD ( fld1, fld2, fld3 ) values ( ?, ?, ? )

and parameterize the queries

Comment: Thanks to correct me. After I change connection string as your suggestion, I still got the same result. File STCRD.cdx still not update. Is it correct?

Comment: @wittakarn, you may need to do a reindex on it, if it had a problem committing the record previously.  Now that the connection is accurate, do FUTURE inserts appear to work, or is it still miss the index.

Comment: How/Why are you looking for a change in the CDX file?   Your only concern needs to be with the DBF file where Data Records and their Fields are stored/read/written (INSERT's, SELECT's, etc all go to the DBF) , the associated CDX, if it was created correctly, will 'follow along'.- but who cares?  Yes, having an Active Index file will expedite your SQL Queries as long as an Index Expression is included as part of your Query , and, if you were working in VFP itself, SEEK()'s can utilize it and Data Table relations can be established, but from a VB.ASP or C# perspective, who cares?

Comment: I haven't yet worked with Visual Studio 2017, but I write VB.ASP code with VS2010 and VS2013 which accesses our legacy VFP Data Tables all the time.   Generally we do that by utilizing a VFP Connection String ( https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/ ).   And we never have to worry about whether or not the CDX file(s) were updated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same situation and am really hoping to find a way to re-index a DBF after inserting new records from OLEDB (vba / vb.net etc)

Comment: @WodChuckChuck, I have not ever had issues with OleDB with inserts and the CDX file which is automatically opened with the DBF, provided you are using the Visual FoxPro OleDB Provider and not the generic Microsoft OleDB provider.  If your system is designed using individual .IDX files which are never opened automatically, you would then be in a different position for updates.  If you ARE using .idx files, I would recommend upgrading to CDX format via INDEX ON ... TAG instead of INDEX ON .. TO.  If you would like assistance, we could do deeper private chat than long comments. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a newbie in visual foxpro. I still did not know after cdx file is
>   changed, the dbf file should be changed as well or not. Can anyone
>   point me to the correct way to add a new record into this kind of
>   database?

In VFP you create a Data Table (a DBF file) on which you can create an associated Index file (a CDX file).
Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (field1 C(10), field2 M, Field3 D)
SELECT MyTable
INDEX ON field1 TAG firstfld
```

Perhaps spending some time at the free, on-line VFP tutorials will help.
[Free On-line VFP tutorials](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx)

Modifications to the Data Table (the DBF file - STCRD.dbf) will automatically 'trigger' the associated Index file (the CDX file) to update.

When you create an ODBC Connection you do so to the DBF file (STCRD.dbf), **NOT** the CDX file.  Once your Data Table 'knows' about its associated Index file, CDX file behavior is 'automatic'.  You don't work directly with the CDX file.

I guess that, for me, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Get the ODBC Connection set up correctly and then explain clearly what it is that you are having trouble with.

Side Note:  A DATABASE is a container (some are 'intelligent' like M$ SQL Server) and others are not (like a VFP Database), but they themselves are Not Data tables.   The Data Table may or may not reside within a DATABASE, but it is the Data Table (not the DATABASE) in which data records 'live'.

Good Luck